# When evaluating an HTMLCollection, why doesn't Chrome DevTools show the item and namedItem methods?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

If you open the DevTools console on any webpage, type `document.forms`, and press Enter, it returns an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), but it doesn't show the [`item`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection/item) and `namedItem` methods. They do exist, since if you evaluate `document.forms.item`, you'll get a reference to the function. So why aren't they displayed when evaluating the `HTMLCollection`?

I understand that they are non-enumerable. But Chrome DevTools shows non-enumerable members anyway, just greyed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like they are grouped under `__proto__`.

[image: logging document.forms in the Chrome DevTools Console]